# iOS - HomeKit: why it takes too long to add a user?

Tags: ios, homekit

I am trying to add a user (`HMUser`) to my home (`HMHome`) by

```
[self.home addUserWithCompletionHandler:^(HMUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"add done!");

        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

as referenced from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/ManagingUsers/ManagingUsers.html

From my phone (whose iCloud email is: me@gmail.com for e.g.), I add a guest (whose iCloud email is: guest@gmail.com for e.g.). Immediately, the guest receives a notification from Apple and has to press `Accept`, as expected. After that, my app can display the guest email, which is correct. The issue is: the guest is very hard to view my shared home. Sometimes I have to wait ~ 2 hours but the guest still cannot view my home layout. I tried to reset wifi/bluetooth on the guest phone but things are not better.

Do you have any ideas about this issue on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'd suggest filing a radar with apple. It's an issue with their sync system (continuity), I'm not sure what the rules for it actually are. There seem to be some rough edges with it, hopefully they will be better in iOS 9.